# ng-repeat: every other value falsely shows as blank.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, element, empty-list

An (edited for readability) version of my json looks like this.

It's actually the reddit front page in json form:

```
{
    "kind": "Listing",
    "data": {
        "modhash": "fb7jljbeer6a0dbec0b7b939c890078b5a92d221b3e2b31cec",
        "children": [
            {
                "kind": "t3",
                "data": {
                    "subreddit": "gifs",
                    "id": "66wssv",
                    "author": "GuacamoleFanatic",
                    "name": "t3_66wssv",
                    "subreddit_name_prefixed": "r/gifs",
                    "domain": "gfycat.com",
                    "thumbnail": "https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/E4FB3khTGQ_D8KP-P7KEVXpB9MzY_XDWUhtPmGnNOuE.jpg",
                    "subreddit_id": "t5_2qt55",
                    "permalink": "/r/gifs/comments/66wssv/8_year_old_tillys_first_couple_of_seconds_wearing/",
                    "url": "https://gfycat.com/VacantRequiredAmethystinepython",
                    "title": "8 year old Tilly's first couple of seconds wearing a bionic hand.",
                    "created_utc": 1492877987,
                    "num_comments": 504,
                }
            },
            {
                "kind": "t3",
                "data": {
                    "subreddit": "IAmA",
                    "id": "66wut7",
                    "author": "JoergS",
                    "name": "t3_66wut7",
                    "subreddit_name_prefixed": "r/IAmA",
                    "domain": "self.IAmA",
                    "thumbnail": "self",
                    "subreddit_id": "t5_2qzb6",
                    "permalink": "/r/IAmA/comments/66wut7/iama_jörg_sprave_the_bald_crazy_german_who_runs/",
                    "url": "https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/66wut7/iama_jörg_sprave_the_bald_crazy_german_who_runs/",
                    "title": "IamA (Jörg Sprave, the bald crazy German who runs \"The Slingshot Channel\" on YouTube.) AMA!",
                    "created_utc": 1492878607,
                    "num_comments": 781,
                }
            },
```

The controller is very simple:

```
angular.module('redditdupe').controller('frontPage', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
function frontPage($scope, $http){

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.reddit.com/.json'
})
.
then(
        function successCallback(response) 
        {          
            $scope.children=response.data.data.children;
        }
        , 
        function errorCallback(response) {

        }
    );

}]);
```

And so is the html:

```
<div class="cartouche" ng-repeat="child in children">
    <div ng-repeat="data in child">             
        <img src="{{ data.thumbnail }}"><br> 
        <a href="{{ data.url }}">{{ data.title }}</a> ({{ data.domain }})<br>              
        {{ data.created_utc * 1000 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z' }} <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/{{data.author}}">{{data.author}}</a>  <a href="#/{{ data.subreddit_name_prefixed }}">{{ data.subreddit_name_prefixed }}</a><br>
        <a href="#/com/{{ data.subreddit_name_prefixed }}/comments/{{ data.id }}/.json">{{ data.num_comments }}</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, ng-repeat shows

- a blank set of results, followed by
- a real set of results,
- followed by another blank set,
- followed by another real set
- ... and so on

Like this:

```
  <--- blank line
()  <--- probably the domain gfycat.com, except it's blank
null < --- dunno
    <--- probably the comment count, but is blank line

8 year old Tilly's first couple of seconds wearing a bionic hand. (gfycat.com)
2017-04-22 09:19:47 -0700 GuacamoleFanatic r/gifs
1959

()  <--- then the same shenanigans again
null 


Seen at the March for Science (i.redd.it)
2017-04-22 09:45:18 -0700 Polymathyx r/pics
338
```

I've googled a lot and this doesn't seem to fit the "consumption cycle" explanation because it's not that the entire collection is displayed in sequence once, and then twice.

This is each element being cycled twice individually, first blank then filled out.

I've been slamming my head against the desk for days.

What is the cause and, more importantly, what is the solution please?

Very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Well, you're iterating over all the values of the child **object** (kind, data). Why do you do that instead of just displaying the data?

Comment: My understanding, I need to do that because the json is a repeatedly nested structure of objects within objects.  Each article is one node, stored within an "all articles" node.  So I need to cycle over "all articles" and  display "each article" within one single bounding rectangle.

Comment: You want to loop over all the elements of the children array. Each element of this array if an object with two attributes: kind, and data. so your outer ng-repeat is necessary (child in children), and child is, as I just said, an object with two attributes, kind and data. There is no reason for the inner ng--repeat. You just want to display child.data.url, child.data.thumbnail, etc.

Comment: You are a god amongst men.  I'm very grateful.  You may have helped me get my dream job.  Marking as accepted. Thanks again.